# C++: Modify a class to make std::swap() work

Tags: c++

What should I change in the [ScintillaEditView](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/f285c5983a8c349bede378375c5ac1952a50143e/PowerEditor/src/ScintillaComponent/ScintillaEditView.h#L183) and [DocTabView](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/a3116818e020e1007b9edd196173256109ef8652/PowerEditor/src/ScintillaComponent/DocTabView.h#L27) classes so that I'd be able to use `std::swap()` on those objects?

For example: in [Notepad_plus::init()](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/f285c5983a8c349bede378375c5ac1952a50143e/PowerEditor/src/Notepad_plus.cpp#L242).

```
std::swap(_mainEditView, _subEditView);
std::swap(_mainDocTab, _subDocTab);
```

Answer (score 1):

`swap` has to either have a move or an assignment operator. Your classes `ScintillaEditView` and `DocTabView` are very complex classes containing windows and other items that cannot easily be assigned or moved. You could try adding a `move` operator, but the usual approach here is not to use `swap` with direct variables, but to use pointers instead. Something like this will probably save you a lot of headaches:

```
shared_ptr<ScintillaEditView> p_mainEditView, p_subEditView;

// and later
std::swap(p_mainEditView, p_subEditView);
```

Here you swap pointers to the actual objects. Pointers can easily be assigned and moved, because they don't actually contain resources (like window), but only point to the resources.

By using pointers you can swap without having to modify the original classes at all.

Comment: `std::swap(_pEditView, _pNonEditView);` is used in the Notepad++ code. But many operations are done by using the objects themselves and NOT the pointers. I'm trying to achieve something that apparently can only be done by swapping the objects. *** Thank you.

Comment: And `_pEditView, _pNonEditView` are both pointers, so you *can* swap them. I haven't found a single  instance in the Notepad++ code you refer to that actually swaps the objects themselves. The `swap(_mainEditView, _subEditView);` statement you posted above does not exist there.

Comment: This was my question - how can I use `std::swap(_mainEditView, _subEditView);`?. Anyway, I need to think about it a bit more. *** Thank you. ***

Comment: Read closely, pay attention to the type of the variable. `_pEditView` is different from `_mainEditView`. `_pEditView` is a **pointer** to a class of type `EditView`. OTOH `_mainEditView` is an **object** of type `EditView`. You _can_ swap pointers, you _cannot_ swap objects of this type.